# CSV file trying to get item after first comma in each row

Tags: c, csv

So I'm trying to make a c program which lets users log in. I have a csv file that lists the current registered users like so: Full name,username,password.

I'm trying to make the user input their username and password, and then scan through each row in the csv file and look for matches, if there are no matches in the row then the program will scan the next row until end of file.. but I'm stuck on how to code this. So far I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {


FILE *fp = fopen(Members.csv, "r");
fgets(user, 100, stdin);
fgets(pass, 100, stdin);


while (!feof(fp)) {

        char username[];
        char password[];
        //trying to use a loop to go through each row and see if there are any matches
```

Comment: Your source code appears to come to an abrupt end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to cope with escaped commas in your CSV, e.g.:

```
"Twizzlebutt, Lord Adelphus", "password123"
```

then use `strtok` to split each line by commas.

If you *do* need to cope with escaped commas, then I suggest you use a CSV library.